# How to use the command \autoref to implement the same effect when use the command \eqref?

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, equations

For example, the first equation of Section 1 in a tex file is numbered in the form (1.1), When we use the commands `\autoref` and `\eqref` for referring it, the compiled pdf file will show Equation 1.1 and (1.1), respectively.

Now the problem is that how can I just use the command `\autoref` to implement the same effect when use the command `\eqref`.

By the way, please do not use the package `cleveref`!

Comment: Would you please add a MWE?

Comment: Although you should know best of course, let me raise the inescapable style question. "(1.1)" is a way of saying "Equation 1.1", so "Equation (1.1)" looks clearly wrong to me.

Comment: @StephanLehmke: Would the following sentence meet with your approval? `"As may be seen by the expressions given in equations 1 and 2, 3 out of 4 dentists recommend Brand-X tooth paste to their patients."` To me, *not* placing parentheses around the first two numerals looks clearly wrong...

Answer (score 23):

Macro `\autoref` of package `hyperref` calls `\<counter>autorefname` followed by a unbreakable space `~` and the number. Finally `\null` is appended (some inheritance from LaTeX). This can be used to define `\equationautorefname` as macro that catches the
equation number in a parameter.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true}

\def\equationautorefname~#1\null{%
  Equation~(#1)\null
}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:pythagoras}
a^2+b^2=c^2\,.
\end{equation}
As may be seen in equation \eqref{eq:pythagoras} or, alternatively,
in \autoref{eq:pythagoras}, \ldots
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result with red links]

Comment: When you first load `babel`, then `hyperref`, this solution somehow does not work. For me, the [the code within the `\makeatletter` commands given in this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/191391/32591) solved the problem.

Comment: @MartinJ.H.Package `babel` should be loaded *before* `hyperref`. And `babel` uses special language name dependent macros for setting up language related stuff. For example, something like the following is needed: `\addto\extrasenglish{\def\equationautorefname~#1\null{Equation~(#1)\null}}`.

Comment: What's the `\null` used for?

Comment: @nn0p It's the end marker for the argument. The second `\null` in the definition text just reinserts the token again, but it could also be omitted.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for your quick response. @HeikoOberdiek

Answer (score 10):

Rather than fiddle with the definition of `\autoref`, you can use the `\tagform@` command (provided by the `amsmath` package) to insert parentheses automatically around cross-referenced equation numbers. This works regardless of the cross-referencing command (`\ref`, `\autoref`, etc) you employ. The following MWE shows how this may be done:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath,hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true}

    % First, save the current form of `\theequation`
    \let\oldtheequation\theequation
    \makeatletter
    \def\tagform@#1{\maketag@@@{\ignorespaces#1\unskip\@@italiccorr}}
    \renewcommand{\theequation}{(\oldtheequation)}
    \makeatother 

\begin{document} 
\begin{equation}\label{eq:pythagoras}
a^2+b^2=c^2\,.
\end{equation}
Looking at equation \ref{eq:pythagoras}, equation \eqref{eq:pythagoras}, or 
\autoref{eq:pythagoras}, \ldots
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This works great for regular equations, but for sub equations it changes it from (1.1a) to (1.1)a. Is there a way to get the subequation letter inside the parenthesis?

Comment: @axsvl77 - Aside: Observe that I wrote this answer nearly eight years ago. For cross-referencing subequations, I wouldn't use the route laid out above. Instead, I would load the `cleveref` package and use its `\cref` and `\labelcref` directives. If you choose the cleveref-based approach, you wouldn't have to change the `tagform@` macro.

Comment: Thanks. Perhaps I should ask a new question.

Answer (score 3):

I think that getting `\autoref` to put parentheses around equation numbers but not around section numbers, etc. would require a lot of hacking (I could be wrong though). However, you can create a new command `\eqautoref`, say, which can be used in place of `\eqref`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\equationautorefname{\@gobble}
\makeatother
\newcommand\eqautoref[1]{(\autoref{#1})}
\begin{document}
\section{A section}
\begin{equation}
a = b \label{eqn}
\end{equation}
\eqautoref{eqn}
\end{document}
```

The `\@gobble` macro eliminates the space that would normally go between whatever `\equationautorefname` expands to ('Equation' by default) and the equation number.

Comment: Will this new command preserve `\autoref`'s "habit" of automatically inserting the appropriate label name (in this case, "Equation") before the number in question?

Comment: @Mico --- No. I thought the OP wanted hyperlinked references that looked the same as the output of `\eqref`.

Comment: Interesting -- I thought the OP's question was directed only at the automatic insertion of parentheses. You may be correct in your interpretation...