# Combining \autoref and \eqref

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing

Say the equation is

```
\begin{equation}
r^2 = x^2 + y^2 \text{.} \label{eq:circ}
\end{equation}
```

Now, if I use

```
\autoref{eq:circ}
```

I get `Equation 1`. How do I get `Equation (1)` (the parenthesis that we get while using `\eqref`) while still maintaining the hyperlink?

*Edited in response to an answer below.*

I have defined two versions of the command to be used at the beginning and in the middle of a sentence:

```
\def\chapterautorefname{Chap.}
\def\sectionautorefname{Sec.}
\def\subsectionautorefname{sub--Sec.}
\def\figureautorefname{Fig.}
\def\tableautorefname{Tab.}
\def\equationautorefname{Eq.}

\newcommand{\Autoref}[1]{%
  \begingroup%
  \def\chapterautorefname{Chapter}%
  \def\sectionautorefname{Section}%
  \def\subsectionautorefname{Sub--Section}%
  \def\figureautorefname{Figure}%
  \def\tableautorefname{Table}%
  \def\equationautorefname~#1{Equation~(#1)}%
  \autoref{#1}%
  \endgroup%
}
```

While using `\Autoref` it says

> Use of `\equationautorefname` doesn't match its definition `\Autoref{eq:llg1}`.

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found this trick in an old document of mine, but I have a feeling that the idea comes from someone else:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\def\equationautorefname~#1\null{Equation~(#1)\null}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \label{eq:circ}
  r^2 = x^2 + y^2.
\end{equation}
\autoref{eq:circ}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Comment too long. Adding it as a post.

Answer (score 13):

The trick described in Svend Tveskæg's answer comes from this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/66150/27635) of Heiko Oberdiek.

If you want it to work with your settings (the command `\Autoref`) you have to use in this way:

```
\newcommand{\Autoref}[1]{%
  \begingroup%
  \def\chapterautorefname~##1\null{Chapter~(##1)\null}%
  \def\sectionautorefname~##1\null{Section~(##1)\null}%
  \def\subsectionautorefname~##1\null{Sub--Section~(##1)\null}%
  \def\figureautorefname~##1\null{Figure~(##1)\null}%
  \def\tableautorefname~##1\null{Table~(##1)\null}%
  \def\equationautorefname~##1\null{Equation~(##1)\null}%
  \autoref{#1}%
  \endgroup%
}
```

Complete MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\def\chapterautorefname~#1\null{Chap.~(#1)\null}
\def\sectionautorefname~#1\null{Sec.~(#1)\null}
\def\subsectionautorefname~#1\null{sub--Sec.~(#1)\null}
\def\figureautorefname~#1\null{Fig.~(#1)\null}
\def\tableautorefname~#1\null{Tab.~(#1)\null}
\def\equationautorefname~#1\null{Eq.~(#1)\null}

\newcommand{\Autoref}[1]{%
  \begingroup%
  \def\chapterautorefname~##1\null{Chapter~(##1)\null}%
  \def\sectionautorefname~##1\null{Section~(##1)\null}%
  \def\subsectionautorefname~##1\null{Sub--Section~(##1)\null}%
  \def\figureautorefname~##1\null{Figure~(##1)\null}%
  \def\tableautorefname~##1\null{Table~(##1)\null}%
  \def\equationautorefname~##1\null{Equation~(##1)\null}%
  \autoref{#1}%
  \endgroup%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \label{eq:circ}
  r^2 = x^2 + y^2.
\end{equation}

\Autoref{eq:circ} some text \autoref{eq:circ}.

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Answer (score 5):

In order to get `\autoref` to insert parentheses around an equation number automatically, i.e., to make it behave like `\eqref`, you could also do the following (which assumes that the `amsmath` package is loaded): Modify the macro `\tagform@` of the `amsmath` package:

```
\let\origtheequation\theequation
\makeatletter
\def\tagform@#1{\maketag@@@{\ignorespaces#1\unskip\@@italiccorr}}
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\theequation}{(\origtheequation)}
```

Note that because of the presence of `@` characters, the redefinition of `\tagform@` has be be wrapped in a `\makeatletter` ... `\makeatother` pair. The macro `\eqref` will continue to work as before, by the way.

A full MWE -- observe that it's not necessary to fiddle any further with the definition of `\Autoref`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\let\origtheequation\theequation
\makeatletter
\def\tagform@#1{\maketag@@@{\ignorespaces#1\unskip\@@italiccorr}}
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\theequation}{(\origtheequation)}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\def\equationautorefname{Eq.}
\newcommand{\Autoref}[1]{%
  \begingroup%
    \def\equationautorefname{Equation}%
    \autoref{#1}%
  \endgroup%
}
\setlength{\textwidth}{3in} % just for this example
\begin{document}
\begin{equation} \label{eq:1}
a^2+b^2=c^2.
\end{equation}

Here's a reference to \autoref{eq:1}. 

\Autoref{eq:1} shows us that \dots
\end{document}
```

Comment: With dvips and ps2pdf the link in the pdf becomes`#equation.(1)%%`. Because of the appended `%%` the links does not work in firefox preview. For dvipdfm it is not a problem.