# Cross reference to chapter or section name using \autoref

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, cleveref, autoref

I want a link to a chapter or subsection name...

```
...
\begin{document}
\chapter{Laravel installation}
\label{laravelinstallation}

Install Laravel by...

\section{PhpStorm}
\label{phpstorm}

After installation, see \autoref{laravelinstallation}...

\end{document}
```

1. I want to output "After installation, see ***Laravel
   installation***..."
2. I must use \autoref{} because I'm compiling Scrivener to Latex via
       MMD mark-up and that's how it's output.

I'm using Hyperref and Cleveref, and spent hours on search engines to the point where my two braincells have ceased to cooperate. Is there an easy/recommended/flamingly-obvious way to do this?

Comment: You're looking for `\nameref{laravelinstallation}` here...

Comment: Okay. I was specific about "I must use \autoref{} because...". Linking a reference to title text is a very common scenario, as is specifically compiled output from excellent software written by experts over thousands of man hours. That's what I want to do, resolve a very common scenario. Is there a healthy way to redefine \autoref to do what \nameref produces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I built upon a helpful answer by karlkoeller at [Combining \autoref and \eqref](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/153496/combining-autoref-and-eqref/153513), although my effort is not as smooth as answers there.

I removed cleveref package and modified \autoref...

```
\renewcommand{\autoref}[1]{%
    \begingroup%
    \def\chapterautorefname~##1\null{Chapter~(##1)\null}%
    \def\sectionautorefname~##1\null{Section~(##1)\null}%
    \def\subsectionautorefname~##1\null{Sub--Section~(##1)\null}%
    \def\figureautorefname~##1\null{Figure~(##1)\null}%
    \def\tableautorefname~##1\null{Table~(##1)\null}%
    \def\equationautorefname~##1\null{Equation~(##1)\null}%
    \emph{see \nameref{#1}}%
    \endgroup%
}
```

It produced this (image from document, not originally posted example)...

[image]

That line ***\emph{see \nameref{#1}}%*** solves my specific problem.

I accept this is a kludge but I looked far and wide for an answer and needed something as quickly as possible. Of course, it redefines \autoref to look like \nameref, thus destroying \autoref's nice *section 1.2.3* formatting. Time permitting, I shall look at how to modify -- unless someone here does it first! ;)