# autoref and braces around equation number

Tags: hyperref, equations

I am writing an article for a journal with AMS math equation style, e.g. "Eq. (1)". I want to hyperref the entire "Eq. (1)" and not merely the "1". Currently I use `\renewcommand{\equationautorefname}{Eq.}`. But this yields an hyperref'ed "Eq. 1". I prefer a solution in which I can continue using `\autoref`.

A solution is presented at [How to use the command \autoref to implement the same effect when use the command \eqref?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52410/how-to-use-the-command-autoref-to-implement-the-same-effect-when-use-the-comman), but it uses `\def` and the journal style prohibits the use of Tex's low-level commands like `\def`, `\edef`, and `\gdef`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you're not willing -- or allowed! -- to modify some lower-level TeX macros, you could still achieve your objective of getting parentheses placed automatically around cross-referenced equation numbers by (a) executing the following instruction in the preamble:

```
\usepackage[nameinlink,capitalize]{cleveref}
```

and (b) using `\cref` instead of `\autoref` to generate cross-references.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink,capitalize]{cleveref}
\setlength\textwidth{3in} %% just for this example
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:pythag}
a^2+b^2=c^2
\end{equation}
A cross-reference to \cref{eq:pythag} via \verb+\cref+.
\end{document}
```

For more on various cross-referencing packages and, in particular, the capabilities of `hyperref` and `cleveref` in this regard, see the posting [Cross-reference packages: which to use, which conflict?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36295/5001)

---

***Addendum***: If you *must* use `\autoref` and want parentheses placed around the cross-referenced equation numbers, it's necessary to redefine the macro `\theequation`. Assuming you also use the `amsmath` package, it's also necessary to modify the auxilliary macro `\tagform@`. The following MWE shows how this may be done. (The directives `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` are needed because some of the code involves the "special" character `@`.)

A side remark: If the journal's guidelines prohibit the use of `\def` in your document, using `\renewcommand` is probably frowned upon as well. If that's the case, you should probably use `\cref` instead of `\autoref` to create cross-references to equations...

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\let\oldtheequation\theequation
\renewcommand\tagform@[1]{\maketag@@@{\ignorespaces#1\unskip\@@italiccorr}}
\renewcommand\theequation{(\oldtheequation)}
\makeatother

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\renewcommand{\equationautorefname}{Eq.}

\usepackage[nameinlink,capitalize]{cleveref}
%% Need to undo the effect of redefinition of "\theequation" to use \cref:
\creflabelformat{equation}{#2\textup{#1}#3}  % No more parentheses around "#1"

\setlength\textwidth{3in} %% just for this example
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:pythag}
a^2+b^2=c^2
\end{equation}

A cross-reference to \autoref{eq:pythag} via \verb+\autoref+.

A cross-reference to Eq.~\eqref{eq:pythag} via \verb+\eqref+.

A cross-reference to \cref{eq:pythag} via \verb+\cref+.
\end{document}
```

Comment: I was under the supposition that hyperref and cleveref cannot be combined, but I was wrong. Thanks. Although my somewhat outdated Tex distribution does not support the nameinlink, I think your `\cref` solution is best. Fortunately I have to submit the tex-files and not the pdf. As for your side-remark, their style guide mentions `\renewcommand` and alikes may be used but not the low-level Tex commands.

Comment: @Bart - Glad you liked my solution. :-) Real quick: How old is your TeX distribution and `cleveref` package that the option `nameinlink` isn't recognized? I'm pretty sure the option has been around for at least two years, and probably longer. If it's at all feasible to do so, you may want to look into updating your TeX distribution.

Comment: It's from November 2011. So yes, I have to update (although I have been saying this too myself way too often...)

Answer (score 10):

The following example defines `\myeqref`, which prepends the equation reference by `Eq.~` and includes the prefix and the parentheses into the link. The prefix can be overwritten by the first optional argument.

The `\autoref` name macros do not have access to the counter, thus the following definition of `\equationautorefname` is just a dirty hack.

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcommand*{\myeqref}[2][Eq.~]{%
  \hyperref[{#2}]{#1(\ref*{#2})}%
}
\def\equationautorefname#1#2\null{%
  Eq.#1(#2\null)%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:einstein}
E=mc^2
\end{equation}
References: \myeqref{eq:einstein} and \myeqref[equation~]{eq:einstein}.\\
Reference: \autoref{eq:einstein}.
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: It works, but can you somehow edit your solution in such a way that I can continue to use autoref for my equations?

Comment: I see the problem with autoref. Pity it cannot be done with `\renewcommand`, although thanks for sharing your solution. If it weren't for Mico's `\cref` solution I would have used your `\myeqref`.

Comment: Hi @Bart, there is [another question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/598941) looking to use this solution with `\autoref`. Can you elaborate on "the problem with autoref" Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a dirty hack, but this works as long as `hyperref` does not change its `\autoref` implementation.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
  \AtBeginDocument{%
    \let\plain@equationautorefname\equationautorefname
    \def\equationautorefname{\plain@equationautorefname\@autoref@insert@tagform}%
    \def\@autoref@insert@tagform~#1\null{~(#1\null)}%
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \label{foo}
  a + b = c
\end{equation}

\autoref{foo}

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

Comment: OP is not allowed to use `\def` (and probably `\let`).