# How to combine hyperref and eqref

Tags: hyperref, align, labels

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=green]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{align} \label{test}
a+b=c
\end{align}
\eqref{test}
\end{document}
```

How can I combine hyperref and eqref such that the braces () are also green and clickable and not only the 1?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Your posting is a possible duplicate of [autoref and braces around equation number](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/191376/autoref-and-braces-around-equation-number). Please check that posting and advise if it's in fact your new posting is a duplicate.

Comment: @Mico I don't see any mention of `\autoref` in the question. How can it be a duplicate of a question dealing with `\autoref`?

Comment: @tohecz: The question referred to by Mico is titled misleadingly, in my opinion, although `autoref` is mentioned in the OP as well in Mico's solution. Both solution (by Heiko Oberdiek and Mico) seem to be applicable for this question as well.

Comment: @Mico: I do not consider the possible duplicate question as related, but not as a duplicate. `\autoref` and `\eqref` are independent from each other, a user might want to use both.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`\eqref` uses `\ref` for the equation number, therefore `\ref` is the link, the surrounding parentheses are not part of the link. The following example redefines `\eqref` to include the parentheses into the link:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=green]{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\eqref}[1]{%
  \hyperref[{#1}]{\textup{\tagform@{\ref*{#1}}}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{align} \label{test}
a+b=c
\end{align}
\eqref{test}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

BTW: Instead of "green" I would use something darker ("darkgreen", ...) for a better contrast to the usual white background.