# redefine \autoref with section number as paramenter

Tags: autoref

In chinese, the word order generated by `\autoref` is different from english, e.g.,

> `Section` 2.1 in chinese reads `Di 2.1 jie`

So is there any possible to redefine `\sectionautorefname` to generate the required cross reference? e.g.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\renewcommand{\sectionautorefname}{di secnum jie}
\begin{document}
\section{test}\label{sec:test}
\subsection{test2}
\autoref{sec:test} will looks like `di 1 jie` instead of `di secnum jie 1`?
\end{document}
```

Comment: I guess you want to look at `cleveref`

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the more powerful package `cleveref`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\crefformat{section}{di~#2#1#3~jie}

\begin{document}

\section{test}\label{sec:test}

\cref{sec:test} will look like `di 1 jie'

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: yes, in fact, I googled to know this can be done by `cleveref`, but is there any possibility to archive what I want without it?

Answer (score 1):

I find an answer inspired by [Heiko Oberdiek](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/191395/19832) , of course this fix is not strong as mentioned in this remark.

I define a command to deal with the `chapter/section/subsection` one in all:

```
\newcommand{\myautoref}[2]{
\expandafter\def\csname #1autorefname\endcsname##1##2\null{The ##2#2}
}
```

then we can use it as

```
\myautoref{chapter}{Chapter}
\myautoref{section}{jie}
```

then `\auroref{lab}` will produce something like `The 1 Chapter`, `The 2 jie`, depending on the level of `lab`.