# How to get brackets by using autoref for align equations

Tags: align, brackets, autoref

I want use autoref to reference equations like this:

Equation (8.19), but my output is: Equation 8.19

I tried to proceed as in (search for "Einstein" )

[autoref and braces around equation number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/191376/autoref-and-braces-around-equation-number)

This is my code

```
\newcommand{\mynewtheorem}[2]{
  \newaliascnt{#1}{definition}
  \newtheorem{#1}[#1]{#2}
  \aliascntresetthe{#1}
  % maybe we will squish some autoref defaults, but who cares?
  \expandafter\def\csname #1autorefname\endcsname{#2}
}
\def\alignautorefname#1#2\null{%
  Equation #1(#2\null)%
}
```

Does anybody have an idea how my code could be adapted to get brackets like above ?

Comment: I guess that `cleveref` is more powerful and robust for this kind of job.

Comment: see here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/191376/autoref-and-braces-around-equation-number