# Redefining format for \autoref for equations causes unwanted format for subequations

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, subequations, autoref, renewcommand

In order to be able to reference the equations in my thesis in the format like "Equation (2.2.3)" using the \autoref command I added the following lines in my preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\let\oldtheequation\theequation
\renewcommand\tagform@[1]{\maketag@@@{\ignorespaces#1\unskip\@@italiccorr}}
\renewcommand\theequation{(\oldtheequation)}
\makeatother
```

as suggested in Mico's answer in this post: [autoref and braces around equation number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/191376/autoref-and-braces-around-equation-number).

This works perfectly for most of the equations but changes the format of the subequations from the standard format like "(2.3.1a)" to "(2.3.1)a". I want to keep to original format for such subequations. Namely, I want the letter to be inside the parentheses. How can I achieve this?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\makeatletter
\let\oldtheequation\theequation
\renewcommand\tagform@[1]{\maketag@@@{\ignorespaces#1\unskip\@@italiccorr}}
\renewcommand\theequation{(\oldtheequation)}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test Chapter}

\section{Test Section}

This is a test equation two including subequations:
\begin{subequations} \label{Eq:MainEquation}
    \begin{equation} \label{Eq:SubEquation1}
        E = mc^2
    \end{equation}
    \begin{equation} \label{Eq:SubEquation2}
        c^2 = a^2 + b^2
    \end{equation}
\end{subequations}

As seen in \autoref{Eq:MainEquation} the labels for \autoref{Eq:SubEquation1} and \autoref{Eq:SubEquation2} are in the wrong format. The letters for the subequations should be inside the parentheses.

\end{document}
```

Screenshot illustrating the problem:[image: Screenshot]

Comment: don't show only snippets. Always show a small but complete example. That makes it much easier to test solutions.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you for your feedback! I have now added a MWE and a screenshot illustrating the problem to the original question.

Comment: The "dirty hack" second answer in the linked question worked for me: `\def\equationautorefname#1#2\null{Equation#1(#2\null)}`, but I'm not sure the limitations of the hack.

Comment: @jessexknight Yes it did! Doesn't seem to have any unwanted bieffects so far. Should have noticed this earlier... However, thank you!

Comment: @jessexknight You can provide your comment as an answer and I can award you the bounty!

Comment: Sure, but let me try to understand the limitations first. I've asked "Bart" in the other question to clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround by redefining the `subequations` environment from `amsmath`.

```tex
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\makeatletter
\let\oldtheequation\theequation
\renewcommand\tagform@[1]{\maketag@@@{\ignorespaces#1\unskip\@@italiccorr}}
\renewcommand\theequation{(\oldtheequation)}

\renewenvironment{subequations}{%
  \refstepcounter{equation}%
  % old
  % \protected@edef\theparentequation{\theequation}%
  \protected@edef\theparentequation{\oldtheequation}%
  \setcounter{parentequation}{\value{equation}}%
  \setcounter{equation}{0}%
  % old
  % \def\theequation{\theparentequation\alph{equation}}%
  \def\theequation{(\theparentequation\alph{equation})}%
  \ignorespaces
}{%
  \setcounter{equation}{\value{parentequation}}%
  \ignorespacesafterend
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test Chapter}

\section{Test Section}

\makeatletter

This is a test equation two including subequations:
\begin{subequations} \label{Eq:MainEquation}
    \begin{equation} \label{Eq:SubEquation1}
        E = mc^2
    \end{equation}
    \begin{equation} \label{Eq:SubEquation2}
        c^2 = a^2 + b^2
    \end{equation}
\end{subequations}

As seen in \autoref{Eq:MainEquation} the labels for \autoref{Eq:SubEquation1} and \autoref{Eq:SubEquation2} are in the wrong format. The letters for the subequations should be inside the parentheses.

\end{document}
```

[image]